# How Do I Resolve "does not denote a properly accessible directory" Exception with UNC Path?

Tags: java, windows, spring, spring-integration

A Spring boot application that implements Spring Integration is attempting to access a UNC path for it's inbound-channel-adapter.

The problem is that I'm receiving the following exception:

```
 13:29:52.925 [task-scheduler-10] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler -
 org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: The path
 [\\server\sharepath] does not denote a properly accessible directory.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Integration config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">

    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="${input.path}" filename-regex="${file.pattern}">
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="500"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="strings" delete-files="true" />

    <int:channel id="strings"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="strings"
                                   output-channel="output"
                                   ref="handler"/>

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="output"
                                       directory="${archive.path}"
                                       delete-source-files="true"/>

    <bean id="handler" class="com.giotta.service.DataHandler"/>

</beans>
```

The properties used in this config are inject with `-D`.

For example, `java jar -Dinput.path="\\\\remote_host_ip\\path\\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the UNC permissions was the issue. Since the windows service wrapper running the spring boot application was running as local user permissions was undeterminable.

I changed the user running the service to an actual user. This allowed spring integration to denote the accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to share the config on the matter. That one for the `inbound-channel-adapter` which causes the problem for you.

Let's take a look to the code!

`DefaultDirectoryScanner`:

```
public final List<File> listFiles(File directory) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    File[] files = listEligibleFiles(directory);
    if (files == null) {
        throw new MessagingException("The path [" + directory
                + "] does not denote a properly accessible directory.");
    }
    return (this.filter != null) ? this.filter.filterFiles(files) : Arrays.asList(files);
}

protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory) {
    return directory.listFiles();
}
```

It's a place from where you see that error. It's reason is exactly in the `java.io.File`:

```
 * @return  An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
 *          directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
 *          The array will be empty if the directory is empty.  Returns
 *          {@code null} if this abstract pathname does not denote a
 *          directory, or if an I/O error occurs.
 *
public File[] listFiles() {
```

So, you really should be sure that you use correct path for your directory.

If you running your Boot application in the embedded Servlet Container mode, you should take into consideration the webapp working directory. In this case your `\server\sharepath` really should be absolute path, not relative.

**UPDATE**

See `java.io.File` JavaDocs:

```
* <li> For Microsoft Windows platforms, the prefix of a pathname that contains a drive
 * specifier consists of the drive letter followed by <code>":"</code> and
 * possibly followed by <code>"\\"</code> if the pathname is absolute.  The
 * prefix of a UNC pathname is <code>"\\\\"</code>; the hostname and the share
 * name are the first two names in the name sequence.  A relative pathname that
 * does not specify a drive has no prefix.
```

Comment: The path is absolute its a UNC path. I think I over edited the IP address that was there originally.

Comment: I take that back. The displayed text is not rending the additional \

Comment: Ah! You mean something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29. When you specify the path for the remote shared dir. Well, we need to understand how Java works with that, first of all...

Comment: How about to try to use "Long UNC": `\\?\UNC\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource` ?

Comment: Please, find an update to my answer. Looks like you should use `\\\\` instead of `\\\`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the long UNC.

Comment: I've used the additional slashes and I receive the same exception. Personally, I think it's got something to do with the remote machine (where the UNC originates). I don't think the properties of the UNC path can be determined.  If it is read/write.

Comment: I‘m getting the same error from a folder poller in case of folder is empty. E.g. whenever spring boot java app is started having folder without files - it fails with the same exception; whenever app is started having a few files in a folder - it‘s running fine. App is running on unix and accessing mounted FS /opt/.../folder . Technically, FS is a mounted samba share but it‘s transparent for the app. While I can workaround by always placing a file to the folder, I don‘t like that. Appreciate any hint on how to get to the root cause and sustainable solution.

Comment: I‘ve overriden *protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory)* in a way that in case of *null* returned from *File.listFiles()*  then I try to create a test file in the same path if works -  I return empty list, otherwise - null. I still don‘t understand what‘s going on, but it works.